# How can I bind onchange and onkeyup with CKEDITOR?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want to integrate a confirmation if we have unsaved form and user cancels, we show him a message. It is working perfectly for inputs but not for ckeditor. This is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').attr('onsubmit', 'disableBeforeUnload();');
    $('form input').attr('onchange', 'enableBeforeUnload();');
    $('form input').attr('onkeyup', 'enableBeforeUnload();');
    $('form textarea').attr('onchange', 'enableBeforeUnload();');
    $('form textarea').attr('onkeyup', 'enableBeforeUnload();');

});

function enableBeforeUnload() {
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        return "Discard changes?";
    };
}
function disableBeforeUnload() {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
}
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: Read the documentation....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [change](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change) event and a [key](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-key) event.

> change event: Fired when the content of the editor is changed.
>
> Due to performance reasons, it is not verified if the content really
>   changed. The editor instead watches several editing actions that
>   usually result in changes. This event may thus in some cases be fired
>   when no changes happen or may even get fired twice.
>
> If it is important not to get the change event fired too often, you
>   should compare the previous and the current editor content inside the
>   event listener. It is not recommended to do that on every change
>   event.
>
> Please note that the change event is only fired in the wysiwyg mode.
>   In order to implement similar functionality in the source mode, you
>   can listen for example to the key event or the native input event (not
>   supported by Internet Explorer 8).

```
editor.on( 'mode', function() {
    if ( this.mode == 'source' ) {
        var editable = editor.editable();
        editable.attachListener( editable, 'input', function() {
            // Handle changes made in the source mode.
        } );
    }
} );
```

> key event: Fired when any keyboard key (or a combination thereof) is
>   pressed in the editing area.

```
editor.on( 'key', function( evt ) {
    if ( evt.data.keyCode == CKEDITOR.CTRL + 90 ) {
        // Do something...

        // Cancel the event, so other listeners will not be executed and
        // the keydown's default behavior will be prevented.
        evt.cancel();
    }
} );
```